# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am trying to make auth context using Firebase. But I got this erro:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'auth')
```

My auth.js

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    return firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        setUser(null);
        nookies.set(undefined, "token", "", {});
```

[image: The error image]

Comment: More code is required. Specifically, the code that should have defined the variable being reported as undefined (firebase)